# Realizar as Mesmas Operações com Diferentes Valores no Método Filter

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde. Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```js
const getCountries = async() => {
  const response = await fetch("https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries");
  const datas = await response.json();

  const selectOnlyCountries = country => 
  country !== 'North America' && country !== 'Asia' && country !== 'South America';

  const countries = datas.filter(({ country }) => selectOnlyCountries(country));
}

getCountries();
```

Ele recebe um *array* de uma *API* com países e continentes, porém, eu só queria os países.

Com isso, cheguei numa solução normal de utilização do *filter*, mas gostaria de não ter que ficar repetindo toda hora o `country !== valor`.

De tal forma, eu tentei o seguinte:

```
const getCountries = async() => {
  const response = await fetch("https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries");
  const datas = await response.json();

  const excludePlaces = [
    'North America', 
    'South America', 
    'Asia'
  ]

  const countries = datas.filter(({ country }) => excludePlaces.some(place => place !== country))
}

getCountries();
```

Não funcionou. A variável *countries* continua com o mesmo *array* de *datas*.

Alguém tem alguma solução para esse problema?

Desde já, agradeço pela atenção!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode substituir a função *some* por *includes*. Some testara todas as alternativas até encontrar um valor positivo, se o country comparado for "North America" por exemplo, ele vai retornar **false** quando comparado com ele mesmo dentro da sua lógica, mas **true** quando comparado com o próximo elemento, enquanto includes vai verificar se o valor desejado existe dentro do array.

O código de comparação seria esse

```
datas.filter(({ country }) => !excludePlaces.includes(country))
```

Mais sobre a função some aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: Na verdade, você pode manter a função Some se trocar o local na negativa (!), o resultado seria esse `countries = datas.filter(({ country }) => !excludePlaces.some(place => place === country))`

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu queria. Não tinha conhecimento desse método *includes* para *array*, pensava que era somente utilizável em *string*. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!